# Erro no retorno de uma função JS

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando armazenar uma imagem com JS e está dando um erro no retorno.

**Mensagem de erro:**

VM85:8 Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement

Estou fazendo isso pelo Selenium com C#, segue meu código:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor Lobj_JS = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Navegador;

            var Lstr_TagImgBase64 = Lobj_JS.ExecuteScript($@"
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var img = document.evaluate('//html/body/div/div[@id='content']/form/div/div/span/div/div/img', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
                canvas.height=img.height;
                canvas.width=img.width;
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,img.width, img.height);
                var base64String = canvas.toDataURL();
                return base64String;") as string;
```

Não consigo tratar esse erro, quando executo no Chrome obviamente eu substituo as aspas simples, ficando no console desta forma:

```
[@id="content"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O return é ilegal por que o código que você está apresentando não é um método ou function que aonde deveria haver um retorno. O seu conteúdo está disponível na variável `base64String`.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document
    .evaluate('//html/body/div/div[@id="content"]/form/div/div/span/div/div/img', 
              document, 
              null, 
              XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
              canvas.height = img.height;
              canvas.width = img.width;
              ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

var base64String = canvas.toDataURL();
//return base64String;
```

Se você deseja que esse bloco de script retorne o valor ao final, você precisa convertê-lo em uma function e executá-la logo em seguida. Contudo podem ser necessários outros tratamentos para garantir o carregamento do `DOM` antes da execução do seu procedimento.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor Lobj_JS = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Navegador;

var Lstr_TagImgBase64 = Lobj_JS.ExecuteScript(@"
    var getBase64String = () => {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = document.evaluate('//html/body/div/div[@id=""content""]/form/div/div/span/div/div/img', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
        canvas.height=img.height;
        canvas.width=img.width;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,img.width, img.height);
        var base64String = canvas.toDataURL();
        return base64String;
    };
    getBase64String();") as string;
```

Comment: Agora faz sentido, eu não tenho muita experiência com JS agora clareou a mente.